# Pre-Select the sole item in a dropdown with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In some instances some of my Bootstrap dropdown controls will only have one option in them, and so therefore I want to pre-select the value in those instances. hardly ground breaking.

The dropdown is in bootstrap, and uses an associated ul for the values, as best shown in the following 
[fiddle of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/andysmiffy/z7w91f98/1/)

The dropdown is defined as...

```
<div class="btn-group postage">
    <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-default dropdown-toggle postDropDown" data-toggle="dropdown">
         select...
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="postList">
        <li id="foobar">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="postitemselector">Why do I have to select when there is only one item in the list?</a>
        </li>
    </ul>                    
</div>
```

I have tried various approaches such as the following, with no success.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#postList option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

How can I pre-select the item in the list via jQuery? (NB I don't want to change the markup of the dropdown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way i sto trigger a manual click event

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
   //Add back the pesky caret which otherwise gets removed on selection.
   $(this).closest(".btn-group").find(".btn:first-child").html($(this).html() + '<span class="caret"></span>');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    //need to do this after teh click handler is added
    $('#postList li:first a').click();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4u87qaj5/)

Comment: Super. Thanks Arun :)